# What is the importance of $R$ being a field in this question?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

Here is the question I am trying to solve (Jeffery Strom, “Modern classical homotopy theory” on pg. 511):

> **Problem 22.39.** Suppose $R$ is a field.
>
> (a) Show that $h^n(?) = \operatorname{Hom}_R( H_n(? ; R), R)$ is a cohomology theory defined on (at least) the category of finite CW complexes.
>
> (b) Show that $u$ is a natural transformation of cohomology theories.
>
> (c) Prove Theorem 22.37.
>
> [(image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yP2Pc.png)

My professor said the importance of $R$ being a field in this question is that it converts the $\operatorname{Hom}$-functor into a right exact functor. But I do not understand how this happened. Could anyone explain this for me, please? I know that either of $\operatorname{Hom}(-,D)$ or $\operatorname{Hom}(D,-)$ are left exact functors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By definition, being a cohomology theory is equivalent to satisfying the Eilenberg-Steenrod axioms. You can check easily that for any ring $R$, $Hom_R (H_n(-;R),R)$ satisfies all but the LES axiom. However, how should we get a LES out of this? Well the obvious way to do this would be to start with the long exact sequence associated to $H_n(-;R)$ and attempt to dualize it. However, $R$ is not generally an injective $R$-module, so homming out to it will not preserve exact sequences. If you find one of these guys, then you are not far from proving there is no way to get a LES for this cohomology theory.

So what is the issue? $R$ is not an injective $R$-module. However, if $R$ is a field, it is and nothing goes wrong.

Comment: Do you know a good book stating the Eilenberg-Steenrod axioms? As Strom book is very bad in that point.

Comment: And how the Hom functor is converted into right exact functor? I do not understand your answer to this point.

Comment: There are many formulations of the axioms. Wikipedia’s article on Eilenberg-Steenrod axioms is decent, but it can be made simpler if you restrict to CW complexes (no need to worry about excision). For based CW complexes, a reduced cohomology theory should be homotopy invariant, take wedges to products, and have a long exact sequence for a CW pair. The first two are very easy to check for your problem, the last is the issue.

Comment: $Hom(-;A)$ is exact precisely when $A$ is injective. This is basically a definition. It is easy to check that a field is injective as a module over itself just by your knowledge of bases.

Comment: My problem is why my professor said $Hom$ will be **right** exact functor in case of a field. And still I do not understand how your answer answers this.

Comment: Oh, I see. according to wolfram, a functor is exact if it is both left and right exact. Thank you for your help!

Comment: How can we prove that it satisfies the suspension axiom? Why cohomology axioms does not contain the excision axiom?